# How to load combo options on a control click (not initially)?

Tags: javascript, html, combobox, dynamic-loading, webix

I am seeking a way to implement the scenario where ui.combo (Webix control) options can be loaded/reloaded from the server only when the user clicks it. Basically, I'm able only to load them initially as follows:

```
{
   view: "combo",
   options: "myurl.php"
}
```

But is there a way to detect the click on a control and load/reload the options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to load options based on the combo item click, then there are 2 methods possible.

**1. Define Options**

You define the options as:

```
$$("mycombo").define("options", "newoptions.php");
```

**2. Load Options**

The load can be performed as:

```
var list = $$("mycombo").getPopup().getList();
list.clearAll();
list.load("newoptions.php");
```

Comment: So as I understand, I need to catch the html `click` event and then execute the code above, right?

Comment: Yep, on the onItemClick event.